# Javascript Raphael strange flickering happens third time I mouseover

Tags: javascript, raphael

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2VKx/3/

When I hover over the circle, the text shows up nicely, but if I remove the mouse, the THIRD time I mouseover, the height and width of the box that matches the dimensions of the text starts growing continuously and there's this weird stroboscopic effect.

```
var rsr = Raphael("holder", '1160', '1400');

xpos = 200;
ypos = 200;
rad = 50;

var rectext, el, txt;

cir = rsr.circle(xpos, ypos, rad);
cir.attr({
    fill: '#444',
        'fill-opacity': 1,
    stroke: 'none'
});

cir.hover(function () {
    this.animate({
        r: rad * 1.2
    }, 200);
    recttext = rsr.set();
    el = rsr.rect(0, 0, 0, 0, 3);
    el.attr({
        fill: '#fff'
    });
    txt = rsr.text(4, 10, "Title text").attr({
        "text-anchor": "start",
        fill: '#000000',
        "font-size": 12
    });
    recttext.push(el);
    recttext.push(txt);
    var att = {
        width: recttext.getBBox().width,
        height: recttext.getBBox().height
    };
    el.attr(att);
    recttext.translate(xpos - recttext.getBBox().width / 2, ypos - rad - 20);
}, function () {
    this.animate({
        r: rad
    }, 100);
    recttext.remove();
    el.remove();
    txt.remove();
        });
```

Comment: Try it with latest version 2.1.2. I din't get flickering with that version.

Comment: That was it. Thank you, I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anto Jurković got it, using Raphael 2.1.2 instead of Fiddle's built-in 2.1.0 solved the problem.